# Nomethod Error not correct need solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller, routes

I have edited this as the answer I previously got was not a fix...I have a list of Counties which have a list of Locations within them. I want to be able to display a list of Counties which can be clicked to reveal another page with a list of locations within them. I cannot fathom why the following set up is not working - I have made the corrections originally suggested to the letter and got exactly the same error as posted. Can someone be so kind as to address exactly what needs to be coded to fix this - incredibly grateful for any help... I have set up my Active Record with

```
class County < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :locations
end



class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :county
   end
```

Controllers as follows:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @locations = Location.scoped
      @locations = @locations.where(county_id: params[:county_id]) if params[:county_id].present?
   end

   def show
      @location = Location.find(params[:id])

   end 
end

class CountiesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @counties = County.all
   end

   def show
      @county = County.find(params[:id])

   end 
end
```

View of Location index

```
<h1> Locations: index</h1>

<ul>
  <% @locations.each do |location| %>
     <li><%= link_to location.name, location %></li>
     <% end %>
</ul>
```

View of County index

```
<p>List of all the locations in <%= @county %></p>

<ul>
  <%= @counties.each do |county| %>
      <li><%= link_to "locations in #{county.id}", locations_path(location_id: location.id) %></li>
       <% end %>
</ul>
```

My routes are:

```
resources :counties
resources :locations
```

Errors are as follows on trying to view counties:

```
NameError in Counties#index
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/static_site/app/views/counties/index.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined local variable or method `location' for #<#<Class:0x00000005a7e108>:0x00000005a7d500>

app/views/counties/index.html.erb:7:in `block in _app_views_counties_index_html_erb__3017893529265312437_33668340'
```

Full trace:

```
activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
app/views/counties/index.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_counties_index_html_erb__3017893529265312437_33668340'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

I have been on this for days so would massively appreciate any help in working out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your County index view makes no attempt to define a `location` variable, yet you try to reference `location.id`. Of course this fails. What did you want `location` to be?

If the intent is to link to the locations's index view, scoped to the given county, you need to fix your routes so that `location` is nested...

```
resources :counties do
 resources :locations
end
```

and then fix your use of `locations_path`:

```
link_to "locations in #{county.id}", locations_path(county)
```

Comment: I was just to post the same answer :)

Comment: I made both these changes and it makes no difference?

Comment: same error when I change routes as suggested plus the link_to "locations in #{county.id}", locations_path(county)

Comment: Hi guys, any other suggestions this still is not a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone starting out with RoR this place is frankly useless - I presented what was clearly a very easy to solve question. This stuff is not easy to learn if its just you and a laptop. Anyway, for what its worth  the answer to my question is as follows:

```
<p>List of all counties</p>

<ul>
  <% @counties.each do |county| %>
      <li><%= link_to "Locations in #{county.name}", county_locations_path(county) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

class CountiesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @counties = County.all
   end

   def show
      @county = County.find(params[:id])

   end 
end

 resources :counties do
   resources :locations
 end

class LocationsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      if params[:county_id]
         @county=County.find(params[:county_id])
         @locations = @county.locations
      else
         redirect_to counties_path
      end
   end

   def show
      @location = Location.find(params[:id])

   end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1> Locations for </h1>  

    <%=@county.name%>

        <ul>
          <% @locations.each do |location| %>
             <li><%= link_to location.name, [@county,location] %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
```